# HTML 5 support in Windows Phone 7 browser

Tags: html, browser, windows-phone-7

Does windows phone 7 browser support HTML5?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/14/ie9-on-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: 7.5 supports HTML5.  For more info, go here http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/mobile/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not yet. You will have to wait for the update [later in the year](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2011-02/15/windows-phone-7-update) that bring IE9 to Windows Phone 7.

The current browser on WP7 is somewhere between IE7 and IE9.

There has just been an upgrade for WP7 rolled out, my guess would be that IE9 (and multitasking) will not arrive until near the end of this year.

Answer (score 2):

WP7 comes with an hybrid of IE7 and IE8, implying no HTML5 functionality.
IE9 which will be released some time soon will support HTML5.

Sources:

- http://www.html5trends.com/browsers/windows-phone-7-html5-not-yet/
- http://wmpoweruser.com/another-html5-demo-on-windows-phone-7/